# Special parameters in replace() JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, replace

[Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on `replace()` shows special parameters that can be used. What I'm trying to do is match a string portion and then use part of the matched portion or part proceeding it. However, I'm using Chrome and I'm either doing it incorrectly or it just doesn't support it. If Chrome doesn't support that method: does it have another method for using a match in the replacement?

Here's an example:

I have a string "bacon &#44 chicken"
I want to take "&#44" and get just the "44" then I want to put the "44" back in the replacement string.

Answer:
Following from DJDavid98's answer, I came to what I wanted `"bacon &#44 chicken".replace(/&#(\d{2})/g, "$1")`

Comment: From the MDN documentation: `The use of the flags parameter in the String.replace method is non-standard.  Instead of using this parameter, use a RegExp object with the corresponding flags. `

Comment: Right, which means Google might have its own non-standard implementation.

Comment: *might*? Have you tested it? You wrote : **If** Chrome does not support...

Comment: I tried it and it didn't seem to work. So I was being generous and leaving the possibility that I'm not flawless and don't always do things perfectly.

Comment: I don't understand your question. In particular, I cannot see the connection between the first part (about flags) and the second part (about getting `44` from the string). The reason you're getting extraneous answers about flags is that you spend your first paragraph taking about flags, when they have no obvious connection to your actual problem.

Comment: *What* did you try? Providing a replacement function, e.g. `"bacon &#44 chicken".replace(/&#([0-9]+)/g, function(match, numcode) { return numcode; })` works just fine and gives you access to the match in the replacement.

Comment: Using DJDavid98's answer, I was able to get a simpler solution.

Comment: @Rhyono If you'd like to mark the question as resolved with your actual final solution, you can post an answer your own question and then accept your answer. (Depending on your rep level, there may be a waiting period.)

Comment: @apsillers I didn't come to the conclusion alone, so I gave that to DJDavid98.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `.exec()` method on a regular expression, like this:

```
/\&#(\d{2})/g.exec("bacon &#44 chicken")
```

This returns:

```
["&#44", "44"]
```

Comment: Thank you, that was nearly what I wanted. I got it the rest of the way `"bacon &#44 chicken".replace(/&#(\d{2})/g, "$1")`

Comment: @Rhyono Glad I could help, but in the future, please be a bit more clear with your questions. Some people are still confused.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the flags at the end of your regex...like `/[^a-z]/g`

Comment: I love how many upvotes you're getting, but that's not what I'm looking for. I'll elaborate. Until I do: enjoy the upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can put flags at the end of the regular expression literal for them to work.

i.e. `/myRegExp/gi`

The snippet that you are referring to on the MDN website refers to the following syntax:
`string.replace(stringToReplace, replacement, 'gi')`

Comment: Your answer does not apply to this question.